# using html data-attributes as css-variable (i.e. text-shadow)

Tags: html, css, custom-data-attribute

i'm trying to use inline data-attributes as variables for css... 
is there any known option to get this run:

```css
.mycss-class {text-shadow: attr(data-textshadow); }
```

```html
<div class="mycss-class" data-textshadow="0 0 0 #000">lorem ipsum</div>
```

chrome dev-tool just reports "invalid property value"

many thanks & kind regards

Comment: from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr: *Note: The attr() function can be used with any CSS property, but support for properties other than content is experimental.*  In other words, `attr` cannot be used with anything other than `content:`, if at all

Comment: If you are putting it into a data attribute, why not just bang it straight into a style attribute instead?

Comment: thank you, i already had feared it... the example was just a tiny version of a more complex construct. so "lorem ipsum" represents a hand full of dom nodes :)

Comment: But if you are outputting that shadow into the data attribute, you can just change that data attribute to be `style="text-shadow: 0 0 0 #000"` and that will give that element the text shadow you are after?  Or am I missing the point

Comment: the point is - i try to avoid inline-styles and keep a good content/code-ratio... if i can do without, ill do :) what i wanted, was "data-cstcolor="#dce568" and use this for textshadows, hovereffects, background-colors... and so on :) it will not work, but it would have been a nice clean solution... so... thanks again :) i guess i'll have to wait for css4 :D

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can do this with [**CSS Custom Properties.**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*)

Support is pretty good, including Edge (but no IE)

```css
p {
  width:80%;
  margin:1em auto;
  text-shadow: 2px 6px 2px grey;
}

p.colored {
  color: var(--mycolor)
}

p.shadowed {
  text-shadow: 2px 6px 2px var(--shadowcolor);
}
```

```html
<p class="colored" style="--mycolor:red;">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam numquam aut aperiam excepturi id quaerat, fugiat, impedit natus maxime voluptates officia? Fuga earum quis exercitationem et fugiat, amet nam officiis?</p>

<p class="shadowed" style="--shadowcolor:green;">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam numquam aut aperiam excepturi id quaerat, fugiat, impedit natus maxime voluptates officia? Fuga earum quis exercitationem et fugiat, amet nam officiis?</p>
```

Comment: nice! thnx @Paulie_D

Comment: Is it possible to do the opposite? As in, use css variables in the html attributes?