# Dynamic values in SASS from HTML

Tags: css, sass

Previously I used to create my helper CSS to aid rapid development.
The contents of helper CSS were like:

```
.margin-10{
  margin:10px!important;
}
.....
```

and in HTML I could use `<div class="margin-10"></div>`

But then found SASS and it's amazing. It really helped me developing applications fast especially its mixin feature. But I have a problem. 
Here is a scenario.

SCSS Mixin is:

```
@mixin border-radius($radius) {
-webkit-border-radius: $radius;
 -moz-border-radius: $radius;
  -ms-border-radius: $radius;
      border-radius: $radius;
 }

 .box {
   @include border-radius(10px);
 }
```

in HTML I can use `<div class="box"></div>`

Is there any possibility to create dynamic classes?
For example if I use `<div class="margin-left-10"></div>` it automatically creates margin left class using mixin.
If I use `<div class="padding-top-100"></div>` padding-top-100 class is automatically created and manipulated using SASS mixin

Comment: No...that's why SASS exists. At least until data attribute stying comes along.

Comment: ...but this might be related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46323117/using-html-data-attributes-as-css-variable-i-e-text-shadow/46326495#46326495

Answer (score 3):

Here a mixin that could help you :

```
@mixin createMargin($min, $max)
  @for $i from $min to $max+1
    .margin-#{$i}
      margin : 1px * $i !important

    .margin-top-#{$i}
       margin-top: 1px * $i !important

    .margin-left-#{$i}
       margin-left : 1px * $i !important

    .margin-right-#{$i}
       margin-right: 1px * $i !important

    .margin-bottom-#{$i}
      margin-bottom: 1px * $i !important

@include createMargin(0, 100) // Choose your min and max value
```

So you will just have to use `<div class="XXX margin-top-40"></div>` to have a 40px margin top on your div

Comment: But this would generate all margin classes from 0-100, right? What about compilation? Will only those classes be compiled which I used or it will compile margin classes ranging 0 to 100.

Comment: Yes the problem is that this would generate all margin classes from 0 - 100 :/